# How to write a SQL query to split the text and add count

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a SQL query to split text with Count:

Input:

```
DFHG, DRTYFGJN, FGH, FGH, NBHFGD, OIUKJH, RTFHGJ, TDHG
```

Desired output:

```
1)DFHG 2)DRTYFGJN 3)FGH 4)FGH 5)NBHFGD 6)OIUKJH 7)RTFHGJ 8)TDHG
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: SQL operates on tables and columns.  It is quite unclear what your data looks like.

Comment: Do you want in one row or multiple rows? here we need to write own logic

Comment: Sql is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a table named yourtable with three columns, something like this

```
First column:  Named ID, Integer, auto incrementing
Second column: Named Bracket, Varchar(1)
Third column:  Named yourtext, varchar(45)
```

you could then insert your string of text, and a fixed value for the bracket, so you end up with a table that looks like this:

```
ID   Bracket   Yourtext
1    )         DFHG
2    )         DRTYFGJN
3    )         FGH

etc
```

you would then query the table as follows:

```
select concat(ID, Bracket, yourtext) from yourtable
```

that query should give you a result looking like this:

```
1)DFHG
2)DRTYFGJN
3)FGH
```